# I don't want the counter to go below "0" in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

I am adding a if condition but still it goes to -1 and then stops decreasing further;

```
const add = document.getElementById('inc');
const less = document.getElementById('dec');
const zero = document.getElementById('res');


let count = document.getElementById('counter');
let update = 0;



add.addEventListener( 'click' , ()=> {
    update += 1;
    count.innerHTML = update;
});

less.addEventListener( 'click' , ()=> {
    if (update <= 0){
        update = 0;
    }
    update -= 1;
    count.innerHTML = update;

});

zero.addEventListener( 'click' , ()=> {
    update =0;
    count.innerHTML = update;
});
```

I am adding a if condition but still it goes to -1 and then stops decreasing further;

Comment: If it is already zero you set it to zero and then you reduce it by one. Pay attention to the order you put your statements in.

Comment: `update = Math.max(update-1, 0)` can spare you having to write an explicit check completely.

Comment: the line `update -= 1` explicitly decrements the `update` variable even when it already equals to `0`. You may replace that (along with the `if` statement) to `update = update > 0 ? update - 1:0` (or something similar, you got the idea).

Answer (score 1):

This block here is setting the count to 0 and then continues to decrement the count.

```
less.addEventListener( 'click' , ()=> {
    if (update <= 0){
        update = 0;
    }
    update -= 1;
    count.innerHTML = update;
});
```

To fix it, you could wrap the `update -= 1` in an `else` from the `if` statement:

```
less.addEventListener( 'click' , ()=> {
    if (update <= 0){
        update = 0;
    } else {
        update -= 1;
    }
    count.innerHTML = update;
});
```